# Passing a style(height || width) which is to be changed in a function?

Tags: javascript, parameters

if i pass a plain string(i.e height or width) from one function `A` to `B` to change a style of an element --

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript" >
function B(temp , attributeToChange , val ){
        temp.style.attributeToChange = val + "px"
}

function A(){

        var to = 200;
        B(this , "width" ,400 ) 
        B( this, "height" , to ) 
}

</script>
<style type="text/css">
    .in{
    width: 100px;
    height: 30px;
    }

</style>


<input class="in" type="button" value="Click Me" onclick="A.call(this)">
</html>
```

This was not possible as i'm not able to use the `attributeToChange` paramenter obtained as a string in `B()`.Is there a way to achieve this (set the attribute of an elem from a string) or is a workaround to -- use `switch (attributeToChange)`??

Comment: temp.style.width = value + 'px'. What's the problem in it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
temp.style[attributeToChange] = val + "px"
```

In javascript, `a["x"]` and `a.x` [mean the same thing](http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.1).

[image]

> "The name of the song is called 'Haddock's Eyes'."
>
> "Oh, that's the name of the song, is it?" Alice said, trying to feel interested.
>
> "No, you don't understand," the Knight said, looking a little vexed. "That's what the name is called. The name really is 'The Aged Aged Man'."
>
> "Then I ought to have said 'That's what the song is called?'" Alice corrected herself.
>
> "No, you oughtn't: that's quite another thing! The song is called 'Ways and Means': but that's only what it's called, you know!"
>
> "Well, what is the song, then?" said Alice, who was by this time completely bewildered.
>
> "I was coming to that," the Knight said. "The song really is 'A-sitting on a Gate': and the tune's my own invention."

In javascript, we have `someObject`, it has an attribute called `width` and the name of this attribute is called `attributeName`. Then,

```
someObject.width == someObject["width"] == someObject[attributeName]
```

Comment: wow.. it was this simple eh.. ??!?.. worked,thanks.. this means `style` is treated as an array in JS??

Comment: No, `style` is an object, the bracket notation is for objects. See http://es5.github.com/#x11.2.1 for details.

Comment: Style is a js object , I guess

Comment: oh.. object.okay.. if `a["x"]` and `a.x` are the same -- it dint work when i tried to access it via `a.x`.. but,worked with `a[x]`.. why is that ??

Comment: `a["x"]` and `a.x` are the same, but `a.aStringVariableThatContainsTheNameOfx` is different, and not valid

Comment: @jashwant updated the code.The `temp.style.attributeToChange` does not change the style.but,`temp.style[attributeToChange]` does.. @Alex : So,the only way to change the style(if its an argument to a function) is by `elem.style[type]` ??

Comment: @Jashwant: if `var x = "height"`, then `a[x]` turns into `a.height`, but `a.x` is equivalent to `a["x"]`, not `a[x]`.

Comment: Yes; `elem.style[type]` is the way to do it as `type` is a variable containing the member name of the `style` object you wish to modify.

Comment: @VivekChandra I think you dont need any clarifications now :)

Darkzaelus, I am not sure why you tagged me , but thanks for clarification.

Comment: @VivekChandra: Updated the answer as it seems to cause some confusion.